# emguCV - Quick calculation of area of the object with holes in binary image

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, emgucv

In my application I online process images (1920x400) with frame rate up to 350 fps. From these images I calculate continuously the area of black object situated in the middle of the picture. The object has often few white holes.

Sample image 1:

[image: Example for you to get an idea of images]

Sample image 2:

[image: Example for you to get an idea of images]

For calculation of area I'm currently using the emguCV function CvInvoke.CountNonZero(Mat) on the thresholded (B/W) image. This solution runs pretty OK, but my problem are the holes, which could mispresent the results rapidly.

I tried to use morphological erosion in order to fill the holes

```
if (erodeEnable)
{
    Mat kernel = new Mat(5, 5, DepthType.Cv8U, 1);
    kernel.SetTo(new MCvScalar(1));
    CvInvoke.Erode(postProcessTempMat, postProcessTempMat, new Mat(5, 5, DepthType.Cv8U, 1), new System.Drawing.Point(0,0), erodeIterations, BorderType.Default, new MCvScalar(0, 0, 0));
}
```

but this operation deforms the object shape dramatically. I want to fill the holes, but keep the outer shape if poss unchanged.

I also tried to use my own method, which column by column searches first upper and lower black pixel and from the positions of these pixels calculate the area of the outer shape.

```
public int getBlackArea(Mat matImage)
{
    Image<Gray, Byte> tempImg = matImage.ToImage<Gray, Byte>();

    int result = 0;
    int coll = 0;
    int upperBorder, lowerBorder;
    const int avFactor = 3;

    result = 0;
    for (coll = 0; coll < tempImg.Width; coll=coll+avFactor)
    {
        lowerBorder = 0;
        while ((tempImg.Data[lowerBorder,coll, 0] > 0) && (lowerBorder < tempImg.Height))
        {
            lowerBorder++;
        }
        upperBorder = iMAGEhEIGHT - 1;
        while ((tempImg.Data[upperBorder,coll, 0] > 0) && (upperBorder > 0))
        {
            upperBorder--;
        }
        result += ((upperBorder - lowerBorder) * avFactor);
        //tempImg.Data[(upperBorder-5), coll, 0] = 120;      // draw the outline for check of function
        //tempImg.Data[(lowerBorder+5), coll, 0] = 120;      // draw the outline for check of function
    }
    //tempImg.Save(@"C:\\pics\INFOoutlined.jpg");
    return result;
}
```

This method returns very good results, but it is too time-demanding.

Don't you have any idea, how to improve my function in order to speed it up? Or don't you have any other idea, how could I reach the results?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: I used opencv, but never emgucv, so just advices to try from my side.
In order to not deform object i could suggest use Close instead of Erode, and in order to speed up you can try use Mat kernel = new Mat(0, 4, DepthType.Cv8U, 1); // with zero for x-axis, and less pixels for y-axis, because the holes on your pictures is long but not high. And do a real use of "kernel" in your code, because now you do not use it

Comment: Don't implement your own algorithms iterating over all pixels, it is very unefficient. Also, why do you need to fill the holes? Are the area of the holes relevant to the area of the black figure? If you want to get the real area of the black object, then your approach counting the black pixels is correct. I don't get why you need to include the white holes.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what morphological operation you choose to perform.

I first binarized the images by selecting an **optimal** threshold.

Then I performed morphological **open**. Unlike stated by *yvs*, morphological **close** does not change the image at all. Since the holes to be filled are surrounded by black pixels morphological **open** solves the problem.

If however, the holes were surrounded by white pixels, morphological **close** would do the trick.

**OUTPUT**

Image 1:

Threshold:

[image]

Morphological Open:

[image]

Image 2:

Threshold:

[image]

Morphological Open:

[image]

As you can see, in both the cases the holes have been filled.